# Object is possibly null or undefined

Tags: angular, webpack

For this particular line of code, I am getting an error that: Object is null or undefined.

```
  private modalService: BsModalService

  const modalRef = this.modalService.show(ABStationDialogComponent);
  modalRef.content.presetStations = this.allStations;
  modalRef.content.editStation = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.editStation)); // Deep copy
  modalRef.content.relatedFrom = this.editAbEntry.fromDate ? this.editAbEntry.fromDate : '';
  modalRef.content.relatedTo = this.editAbEntry.toDate ? this.editAbEntry.toDate : '';
  modalRef.content.editStations = this.editStations;
  modalRef.content.pageReady = true;
```

I tried to use Optional Chaining but did not help. then I am getting this error:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.
```

Please look at the image and the error.

[image]

Even tried to wrap up with if statement did not help as well. I am getting this error in my angular app after installing webpack 5.

can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: what does `this.modalService.show(ABStationDialogComponent);` return?

Comment: it is a bootstrap modal service @depperm

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/modal/bs-modal.service.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down a little:

Line 276: `this.modalService.show()`

The method "show()" on your modalService has a no explicit return type, meaning that it can return `null`, `undefined` or any object for that matter.

If the object is `null` or `undefined`, the properties on the `modalRef` (like content) might not be there, that is why your IDE is marking it.

**Fix**

To fix this issue, you can wrap the `modalRef.content` in an **if** statement and make sure the content property is available.

instead of using a question mark (which indicates that the `modalRef` is optional), you can then use an exclamation mark to tell your IDE that the modalRef is always set.

```
if (modalRef && modalRef.content) {
  modalRef!.content.presetStations = "anything"
}
```